# Re-initialize a panel

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, user-interface

I use a panel to gather input from the user. It's called from a button click on the main window. If a user clicks the red button on the panel, I need to reset the visibility and content of it's controls (3 boxes and two text edits) in case it's opened again.

The method below fires, but when the user opens the panel again, the elements have not been reset.

```
-(void)windowShouldClose:(NSNotification *)note
{
  [CWStop setStringValue:@""];
  [CCWStop setStringValue:@""];
  boxAzEl.hidden = NO;
  boxCCW.hidden = YES;
  boxCW.hidden = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue looks like when you are launching the panel you are setting the value. And when you are closing you are resetting the same. But you are not retaining the same.
So you need to retain your updated value every time.

Comment: Changing to "@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet NSBox *boxCCW;"
from "@property (unsafe_unretained) IBOutlet NSButton *btnCalOK;" didn't change behavior.

Comment: not like that you have to store the old value that i meant

Comment: Do you mean something like write to disc and read back in when the panel opens again?  I don't think there's anything that runs at re-opening after the controls are created is there?

Comment: Thanks for your effort. The solution is to set the window's delegate to Calibrate instead of File's Owner.